# Having asset issue invalid _type 'image' in Sanity, when trying to name it different

Tags: graphql, sanity

Mates.

I am stuck in a very serious problem and need guidance.

I created a schema

```
export default {
 title: 'Blog Content',
 name: 'blogContent',
 type: 'object',
 fields: [
  {
   title: 'Title',
   name: 'title',
   type: 'string',
  },
  {
   title: 'Content',
   name: 'content',
   type: 'array',
   of: [
    { type: 'block' },
    {
     type: 'image',
     fields: [
       {
         name: 'alt',
         type: 'string',
       },
     ],
    },
    {
     type: 'youtube'
    },
    { type: 'testimonial' }, { type: 'button' }
   ],
   lists: [
    { title: 'Bullet', value: 'bullet' },
    { title: 'Numbered', value: 'number' }
   ]
  }
 ],
}
```

But having top-level schema issue,

[VsCode Schema Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEv96.png)

But there is one thing to mention

I can easily seperate the image object from array and make it top-level but then i will get image reference issue, so need help to move asset reference from image to like blogImage because there is no name attribute given in image object, and also cannot name it with default types like image.

Doing so will result in below image because i made it top-level schema with different name. so reference broke
[Sanity Studio Image Reference Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6bg1.png)

I am trying to move reference somehow to another name like blogImage because there are hundered of images so is there any way to create a script to move all the image references to another names.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. See here for details on why and other tips for asking good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please Check it now